# Android Wear Google Play Services

Tags: android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch, android-wear-data-api

I developing an android wear app. While synchonization the data I have to use Google Play Services in order to update information between devices (phone and wear).
I have some problems:

1. While synronization Google Play Services have to update to the lates version. The original version is 8.7. But after sycning they become 9.8 ! Not the latest: 10.0.1! WHY?  The phone have got the latest (10.0.1). So, it is not possible to sync the data.
2. Will this problem appear for published APK file? Will users see the same error on their devices? Is it a problem only for applications in development? Or what? I will not sure that the application work properly in all devices! Am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play services out of date. Requires 11011000 but found 10289574](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584698/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-11011000-but-found-10289574)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to decrease Google Play Services' version in both handheld and wearable applications.
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.6.1'`

Comment: My practice on this for my own apps is "the lowest version that supports the functionality I need" - and that varies by app. My lowest right now is 8.4.0, my highest is 9.8.0.

Comment: Very true. Furthermore: if the watch runs the Play services version lower than demanded by the app, it will not get installed on the watch, resulting in 1-star ratings.

Comment: As I understood current wearable soft has got awful APIs :(