# GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date. Requires 11011000 but found 10298470

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing an android app with Firebase. I am testing my app in AVD emulator pixel. But I keeps on getting error

> Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11011000 but found 10298470.

Answer (score 6):

**Update; June 23**

Emulator system images containing Google Play services compatible with 11.0.1 were relased today.  If you get the error message shown in the title of the post, you need to use the SDK Manager to update to the latest emulator image versions.

---

The release of the emulator system images lags the release of Google Play services versions.  I checked the released x86_64 system images for APIs 24, 25, 26.  None of them support Google Play version 11.0.1. I doubt that any released images do.

If you want to test with an emulator, you will need to downgrade to building with version 10.2.6 of the Firebase libraries.

Comment: Yeah It start working with Android 7.1.1 thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You probably aren't using an emulator device that is flagged with the "Play Store"

---

#### **Step 1**

Click on the "AVD Manager" icon

[image]

---

#### **Step 2**

Click on "Create Virtual Device"

[image]

---

#### **Step 3**

Select an emulator from the list that is **flagged with the "Play Store" icon**

[image]

---

#### **Step 4**

Click on Download

[image]

---

#### **Step 5**

Give it a name and click on Finish

[image]

---

#### **Step 6**

Use the newly created emulator device from the list

[image]

---

#### **Step 7**

Click on the emulator's "..." button

[image]

---

#### **Step 8**

Click on the "UPDATE" button, and follow the instructions in the emulator

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312782/4455570

Make sure you log into Google Play on the emulator **FIRST** before clicking the update button. Once you log in, Google Play Services might update automatically as happened to me.