# Google Play services out of date in emulator of wear

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, wear-os

I want to try the Google Maps Wear Activity in the emulator of Android Studio to develop a custom app.
However, the plain sample doesn't work because of the following error:

> Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298574.

I read the following thread:
[Google Play services out of date. Requires 11011000 but found 10289574](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584698/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-11011000-but-found-10289574)
and
updated the Google Play of mobile. Additionally, I confirmed the emulator and Android Studio is the latest version.
However, I couldn't solve the error and understand how to update the Google Play for wear.

Comment: Can you try using Android Nougat for both emulators?

Comment: Hi, @noogui, Thank you for your reply!
I tried using Android Nougat for both emulators, but nothing changed.
Don't you know how to update the Google play services of android wear?
The version of Google play services of android wear is 10.2.89.
I think this is the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage this problem by downgrading Google play services.
I used the following codes:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
```

instead of the following codes:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'.
```

Best regards