# FirebaseAuth signInWithEmailAndPassword() in v11.4.2 not responding

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have upgraded to Firebase Android libraries v11.4.2 to try out Firestore on my Android app.  However, when I try to use FirebaseAuth to login with signInWithEmailAndPassword(), my app just hangs.  I have confirmed with the debugger that the signInWithEmailAndPassword() call is made, but the callback is never called.  I have also reverted back to v11.0.2 with no other code changes and it works as expected.

Has anyone else had this problem and how did you fix it?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: can you share any logs or code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The emulator had the wrong version of Play services.  I followed the directions in the first answer for this question: [Google Play services out of date. Requires 11011000 but found 10289574](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584698/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-11011000-but-found-10289574/45312782) and it worked.